# How to search for a word which doesn't end with another word? regex

Tags: regex

i need to search for word `strong` but not `strongman` ,

for example:

```
   strong fs asfa strong saff strongman sa strong
```

the regex should return 3 matches .

I've tried different thing:

1.

```
"<(strong)(man){0}>"
```

2.

```
"<(strong)(man.*){0}>"
```

what i am trying to do is to search for the word **strong** which is not followed by **man**

any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: which regex engine are you using?

Comment: @hek2mgl thank you for your comment, i am using php

Comment: you should use regex word boundary `\b(strong)\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `\b`.

use `\bstrong\b`

See demo.
https://regex101.com/r/jX1rN4/3

EDIT:

for the new condition use

```
\bstrong(?!man\b)
```

See demo.
https://regex101.com/r/jX1rN4/4

This works as

`\b` is word boundary so detect `strong` and not `asbdstring`

then after `strong` we add a `lookahead` stating there should not be `man` (again `\b` so that there can be `mann`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is doesn't work because it won't return strong if it was followed by word which is not man, for example "strongb"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i see it's working can you please explain how your regex works . thanks

Comment: hello vks, can you please tell me how could i search for strong which is not followed by   ( man   or   woman )   ?  thanks

Comment: @david `\bstrong(?!(?:man|woman)\b)` or `\bstrong(?!(?:wo)?man\b)`